# MVC toggle buttons

Tags: asp.net-mvc, togglebutton

I have a group of buttons at the moment which users can select to filter out a grid. The problem is that after one of the buttons is clicked, the user does not know the current active filter that was applied. So can anybody help me to figure out how to have these group of buttons act as toggle buttons (spec is to change the button background color for active button)?

Please note this is in MVC and there is an onclick event bound to each of the buttons which calls a javascript function.

Answer (score 1):

If you ar using jquery UI you could try using the button plugin [configured as a checkbox](http://jqueryui.com/demos/button/#checkbox)

Comment: how to pass for example to controller that B was clicked or not , I mean if I have list of options and I add or remove from it the options according to toggle

Answer (score 1):

You haven't given much detail on how you've wired up click events, but in your click handler for the buttons, you could do something like this:

```
var button = document.getElementById("button");
button.onclick = function() {
    if (!this.style.backgroundColor) {
        this.style.backgroundColor = 'yellow';
    }
    else {
        this.style.backgroundColor = null;
    }
}
```

There are other ways to do this if you're using jQuery or another JS framework.